# Parsing issues with socketio data with objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, socket.io

I am getting a response from a socketio server and I am not sure how to parse it. I receive an event from the socketio server that has a packet.

Here is the packet broken down by elements and trace statements:

```
po packet => <SocketIOPacket: 0x2561a1a0>

po packet.args => <__NSArrayI 0x256093e0>(
{"thing_id":"519192832f9053000001","bearing":0,"mph":0,"lng":-75.14617,"on_call":true,"lat":39.98132314,"name":"BJLKD"}
)

po packet.args[0] => $2 = 0x25606f60 {"thing_id":"519192832f9053000001","bearing":0,"mph":0,"lng":-75.14617,"on_call":true,"lat":39.98132314,"name":"BJLKD"}
```

I am trying to access the elements and I have tried converting it to an NSArray, NSDictionary, leaving it as is and try to access it if it were an NSArray and an NSDicitionary and nothing works.  Nothing but selector errors.

Anyone have any clues?

Comment: This question seems related to [your other question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16555215/335858). You may want to delete the old question.

Comment: Please edit your question rather than reposting. Editing bumps the post.

Comment: Jesus. I closed the other question.

Comment: Don't delete and repost in the future. Just edit it to respond to requests for clarificaiton.

Comment: Like this one: the `args` object is already an array, which contains dictionaries. What do you mean, you're trying to convert it? How are you trying to do that? Exactly what code are you using to try to access it as an array?

Comment: Its an array with a string. The string is I guess json? I need to get the data via keys so I want value for "bearing" and the value for "mph" keys. I can't seem to access it.

Comment: The item inside the array is a dictionary. `packet.args[0][@"bearing"]`

Answer (score 0):

The solution is:

```
 NSDictionary *JSON =
[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: [packet.args[0] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
                                options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                                  error: &jsonParsingError];
```